# Does SQL Server 2008 R2 Web edition support CSV and XML export?

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

Does SSRS in SQL Server 2008 R2 Web edition support CSV and XML export? This info is not included in Microsoft's [feature matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx).

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To finally answer my question: No, it does not. I looked it up in Microsoft's feature matrix for SQL Server quite some time ago.
'